# count elements = "" in tuples inside a list of lists

Tags: python, list

I have a list of lists of tuples:

```
[[("AA","AA"),("QQ","")],[("CC",""),("QQ","")],...]
```

I am trying to count the number of empty values `""` in the second value of the tuples. In the case above it would be:

I needed the answer in a list with the sum of occurrences for each nested list (in the example above it would be [1,2,...].

I was trying something like that

```
with open(file, 'r') as f:
    obj = pickle.load(f)
    count=Counter(elem for elem in el for el in obj if elem[0]=="")
```

Is it possible to somehow use 2 "for" for nested lists?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a list comprehension with `sum()` and a generator expression:

```
[sum(1 for t in tups if t[1] == '') for tups in obj]
```

Demo:

```
>>> obj = [[("AA", "AA"), ("QQ", "")], [("CC", ""), ("QQ", "")]]
>>> [sum(1 for t in tups if t[1] == '') for tups in obj]
[1, 2]
```

Comment: Is there a reason to use `sum` over, say, constructing a list and taking its length? Is `sum` faster because it can take a generator as input?

Comment: @mdml: Why create a whole list when all you need to do is count? `sum()` with a generator expression does just that; count the number of times there is a `t[1] == ''` element in the list.

Comment: @mdml: constructing a list takes CPU and memory (and allocating memory is relatively expensive), just to ask for its length. You then discard the list object again. Quite a waste, really.

Comment: Understood, yet taking the length is faster (by nanoseconds) on my machine.

Comment: @mdml: How long are your lists? And how did you compare the timings? Nanoseconds just means "too close to call".

Comment: I'm just using your code and the example data here, using `timeit`.

Comment: @mdml: Then nanoseconds is 'too close to call'. With larger datasets, however, the difference is more striking.

Answer (score 1):

```
[sum(0 if x[1] else 1 for x in sub_lst) for sub_lst in big_list]
```

Comment: Why the conditional expression instead of filtering?

Comment: @MartijnPieters -- No real good reason.  I don't like `if t[1] == ''` since strings have the explicit boolean testing.  but I didn't really like `if not t[1]` either ... So this seemed to be an OK compromise.  I doubt that there will really be a very big performance implication either way.

Comment: @MartijnPieters -- My first thought was actually `sum(not bool(x[1]) for x in sub_lst)`, but there's a little too much magic there for the beginning python users and it's less explicit so I discarded it (which is why your answer came in about 30 seconds before mine did)